# Angular hide and show buttons not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following requirement that is not working with my current code. I need to hide or show buttons which sit in my app header component based on a users role.

The users role comes from session storage which is being called in a service file.

```js
     setStoreData() {
        const data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(`oidc.user:${environment.accessTokenApiUrl}:${environment.clientId}`));
        return data;
      }
```

I then consume the service in my header component on ngOnit and assign it to a variable

```js
      ngOnInit() {
            this.userRole = this._storeService.setStoreData().profile.role;
      }
```

Then comes the function to enable or disable my header button

```js
      isDisabledCorporates(): boolean {
        if (
          this.userRole == 'HR Admin' ||
          this.userRole == 'HR Recruiter' ||
          this.userRole == 'HR Manager' ||
          this.userRole == 'Candidate' ||
          this.userRole == 'Operations administrator' ||
          this.userRole == 'Internal Account Manager') {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }

      isDisabledArchive(): boolean {
        if (  this.userRole == 'HR Recruiter' ||
              this.userRole == 'HR Manager' ||
              this.userRole == 'Candidate' ||
              this.userRole == 'Operations administrator' ||
              this.userRole == 'Internal Account Manager') {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
```

Lastly I have the html code as follows

```html
    <nav *ngIf="userRole">
      <div>
        <div>
          <button class="nav-link-btn" [routerLink]="['/corporate/dashboard']" *ngIf="isDisabledCorporates()"> Corporates </button>
          <button class="nav-link-btn" [routerLink]="['/archive']" *ngIf="isDisabledArchive()"> Archive </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

The problem is that the code does not seem to disable the corporate button and my current user is HR Admin. Any ideas why?

Comment: Try printing `userRole` somewhere in your DOM. Maybe it's a case issue or incorrect value?

Comment: @RehbanKhatri I consoled it out and it comes through as "HR Admin"

Comment: It is not the same as mentioned below. The old answer pertaining to old code was marked correct. Please read carefully before commenting. Flagged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be inverted logic. The *ngIf structural directive will display the element in the DOM if the method returns true. I recommend adding a ! operator.

```
*ngIf="!isDisabledCorporates()"
```

```
*ngIf="!isDisabledArchive()"
```

Comment: I'm happy to help.

Answer (score -1):

You should use ===, and why don't you try first if your function is returning value or not.

```
isDisabledCorporates(): boolean {
```

return true; // or try with return false;
  }

if this works fine then go ahead an try with the complete code and before all that verify what are you getting in this.userRole after ngOnInit() execution. put a debugger otherwise and see how the function execution is happening.